# vulkan unable to find validation layers

Tags: std, stdvector, vulkan, validation-layers

I'm following a vulkan tutorial and when i'm trying to check for validation layer support.
the function always returns false when it is supposed to return true.
this is the code:

```
bool app::checkValidationLayersSupport() {
uint32_t layersCount = 0;
vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties(&layersCount, nullptr);

std::vector<VkLayerProperties> availableLayers(layersCount);
vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties(&layersCount, availableLayers.data());
std::cout << layersCount << "\n";


for (const char* layerName : validationLayers) {
    std::cout << layerName << "\n";
    for (const auto& layerProperties : availableLayers) {
        if (strcmp(layerName, layerProperties.layerName) == 0) {
            std::cout << layerProperties.layerName << std::endl;
            return true;
        }
    }
}

return false;}
```

`validationLayers` value is { "VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation" } (std::vector<const char*>)

after `vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties` `LayersCount` value is 5 so i think the problem is that the second `vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties` can't change the value of `availableLayers` so it remains empty

edit:
I checked it and the second `vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties` is  initializing the vector but the needed validation layer is not in it.

fix: i reinstalled the sdk

Comment: How have you installed the SDK?